# Getting and Setting Rotation in XNA around the Center of my Model with XNA

Tags: xna, matrix, rotation, angles

Alright, so I'm currently debating how I want to do this.  Basically this is what I'm trying to accomplish.

I've created a system to allow me to make my environment a little bit easier.  I'm currently setting up a way to edit my models that I'll be rendering a bit easier.  Currently I'm displaying their properties in a .NET Property Grid like so:

[image]

As you can see, I want to be able to rotate my model via 3 separate values.  One represents the rotation around the X axis, one for the Y axis, and one for the Z axis.  I'll be specifying the amounts in degrees (and converting to radians when necessary).  I also want to have it rotate around the center of the object.

Here are the things I have to think about:

- How to I unbiased rotate my model (considering I can only rotate one axis at a time via `Matrix.CreateRotation[X/Y/Z](angle)`
- How to make sure it rotates around the center
- Extract these three angles back out from a Matrix
- How to properly rotate them so that it handles it all intuitively

What do you guys think?

Comment: You know you can have two calls to Matrix.CreateRotation() in the same line, thus calling rotation on two or more axises simultaneously, right?

Comment: @Fibericon :: Last I checked, `Matrix.CreateRotation()` doesn't rotate any axises simultaneously.  My understanding is that it rotates them in the order that you multiply them which creates a different final rotation depending on the order.  Take a look at my first bullet where I have addressed this.  Correct me if I'm wrong, but I would like to see some credible resources because even from my testing I've only been able to confirm my beliefs as to how `Matrix.CreateRotation()` works.